# Java Swing--- No errors or exceptions, but program doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, swing

Before I start, I've looked over my code for literally 4 hours till I couldn't look any more, and coming here was a last resort, don't want to waste anyones time with dumb questions, but, anyways; Working on my simon game to help teach myself Java, and several problems. First off, the showPattern method seems to be all wonky. Notably, it doesn't seem to be showing the same pattern with one new color each time as intended. Also, when the correct button is clicked, the current/high score is not updating. These are the only errors I've detected so far, there may be others.

I'm only posting the entire program so that you can copy and test it. Sorry if it's a little long. I really appreciate any help, please don't be cynical like some of the other people.

```
package simon;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;


/**
 *  Main Class
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
class Simon
{


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        window.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    // Static object creations.
    public static GameWindow window = new GameWindow();

    // Variable declarations.
    public static final String[] colors = {"Green", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue"};
    public static ArrayList<String> pattern = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int currentScore = 0;
    public static int iterator = 0;
    public static boolean isPlayerTurn = false;
    public static int highScore = 0; // TEMPORARY
}

/**
 * Class for main game window.
 * @author Chris
 */
class GameWindow extends JFrame
{
    GameWindow()
    {
        // Set basic properties of frame.
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Simon");
        setResizable(true);
        setLocation(DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_LOCATION, DEFAULT_VERTICAL_LOCATION);
        // PLACEHOLDER FOR IMAGE ICON

        // Adding Border layout helper panel.
        BorderPanel borderPanel = new BorderPanel();
        add(borderPanel);
    }

    // Declaring window positioning constants.
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 800;

    // TEMPORARY PLACEHOLDER FOR SCREENSIZE CALCULATIONS
    public static final int DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_LOCATION = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_VERTICAL_LOCATION = 0;
}

/**
 * Class to hold the buttonsPanel
 * @author Chris
 */
class ButtonsPanel extends JPanel
{

    // Creating JButtons for gameplay.
    public static JButton greenButton = new JButton();
    public static JButton redButton = new JButton();
    public static JButton yellowButton = new JButton();
    public static JButton blueButton = new JButton();

    ButtonsPanel()
    {

       setBackground(Color.BLACK); 

       // Setting grid layout (with spaces)
       setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 20)); 

       // Setting background color of buttons.
       greenButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  // NEED COLOR CONSTANTS
       redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);  
       yellowButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);    
       blueButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

       // Add buttons to panel. (In order)
        add(greenButton);
        add(redButton);
        add(yellowButton);
        add(blueButton);

       // Creating ActionListeners for 4 main buttons.
        ActionListener greenAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                greenClicked();
            }
        };

        ActionListener redAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                redClicked();
            }
        };

        ActionListener yellowAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                yellowClicked();
            }
        };

        ActionListener blueAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                blueClicked();
            }
        };

            // Associate actions with buttons.
        greenButton.addActionListener(greenAction);
        redButton.addActionListener(redAction);
        yellowButton.addActionListener(yellowAction);
        blueButton.addActionListener(blueAction);
    }

        public static final int delay = 400;

        // Handling button activations.
        public static void greenClicked()
        {
            // Handling button Coloring/timing.
            greenButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            greenButton.repaint();

            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                greenButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
            };

            Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            // Handling button Action
            if(Game.isPlayerTurn == true)
            {
                Game.check("Green");
            }
        }

        public static void redClicked()
        {
            // Handling button color and timing.
            redButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            redButton.repaint();

            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                    redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            };

            Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            // Handling button actions.
            if(Game.isPlayerTurn == true)
            {
                Game.check("Red");
            }
        }

        public static void yellowClicked()
        {

            // Handling button color and timing.
            yellowButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            yellowButton.repaint();

            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                    yellowButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            };

            Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            // Handling button actions.
            if(Game.isPlayerTurn == true)
            {
                Game.check("Yellow");
            }
        }

        public static void blueClicked()
        { 
            // Handling button color and timing.
            blueButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            blueButton.repaint();

            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                    blueButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            };

            Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            // Handling button actions.
            if(Game.isPlayerTurn == true)
            {
                Game.check("Blue");  
            }
        }

}
/**
 * Menu buttons panel.
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
class MenuPanel extends JPanel    
{    

    static JButton startButton;
    static JButton scoreDisplay;
    static JButton highScoreDisplay;

    public MenuPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Menu panel buttons.
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        scoreDisplay = new JButton(String.valueOf(Simon.currentScore));
        highScoreDisplay = new JButton(String.valueOf(Simon.highScore));

        // Adding Buttons
        add(startButton);
        add(scoreDisplay);
        add(highScoreDisplay);

        // Setting background colors
        scoreDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        highScoreDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        startButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        // Disabling displays
        scoreDisplay.setEnabled(false);
        highScoreDisplay.setEnabled(false);

        // ActionListeners for menu buttons.
        ActionListener startButtonAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                Game.startGame();
            }
        };
        startButton.addActionListener(startButtonAction);

        startButton.setFocusable(false);
    }
 }

/**
 * Border Panel support class.
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
class BorderPanel extends JPanel
{

    BorderPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new MenuPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new ButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
/**
* Main game logic class.
* @author Chris
*/
class Game extends Simon
{   

// Resets variables for new game.
public static void startGame()
{
    isPlayerTurn = false;
    pattern.clear();
    currentScore = 0;
    iterator = 0;

    gamePlay(); // Should Start game
}

public static void gamePlay()
{
    if (isPlayerTurn == false)
    {
        computerTurn();
    }
    else
    {
        playerTurn();
    }
}

public static void computerTurn()
{
    // Isn't working.
    ButtonsPanel.greenButton.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonsPanel.redButton.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonsPanel.yellowButton.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonsPanel.blueButton.setEnabled(false);

    iterator = 0; // So CPU can use iterator to show pattern.
    Random generator = new Random();
    int randInt = generator.nextInt(4);
    String randColor = colors[randInt];
    System.out.println(randColor); // For testing.
    pattern.add(new String(randColor));
    showPattern();
}

public static void playerTurn()
{
    iterator = 0;
    ButtonsPanel.greenButton.setEnabled(true);
    ButtonsPanel.redButton.setEnabled(true);
    ButtonsPanel.yellowButton.setEnabled(true);
    ButtonsPanel.blueButton.setEnabled(true);
}

/**
 * Handles scoring and checks inputs for correctness.
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
public static void check(String lastInput)
{
    if (lastInput.equals(pattern.get(iterator)))
    {
        iterator++;
        if(iterator > currentScore)
        {
            currentScore++;
            MenuPanel.scoreDisplay.repaint();
            if(currentScore > highScore)
            {
                highScore++;
                // PLACEHOLDER TO WRITE HIGHSCORE TO FILE.
            }
        }
        if (iterator == pattern.size());
        {
            isPlayerTurn = false;
            computerTurn();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        gameOver();
    }
}

public static void showPattern()
{
    int j = 0;
    while (j < pattern.size())
    {
        String showerHelper = pattern.get(j); // Helper variable.
        switch (showerHelper)
        {
            case "Green" : ButtonsPanel.greenClicked();
            case "Red" : ButtonsPanel.redClicked();
            case "Yellow" : ButtonsPanel.yellowClicked();
            case "Blue" : ButtonsPanel.blueClicked();
            break; // Fallthrough handler.
            default: System.out.println("Error: Invalid value for pattern"
                    + " ArrayList, or improper storage of variable in the"
                    + " showerHelper variable.");
        }
        j++;
    }
    isPlayerTurn = true;
    gamePlay();
}

public static void gameOver()
{
    System.out.println("YOU LOSE!");
    // PLACEHOLDER TO PLAY GAMEOVER SOUND
}

} // End of game class.
```

As a side question, how would I go about playing a tone when a button is activated, like the simon handheld game? Also, how can I save highscore in some way that when the program closes, highscore is saved for next use?

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep` in Swing never ends well :)

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Note:  The use of a lot of `static` methods has a bad code smell to it.  There should be no need to make them `static`.

Comment: Thanks, I had heard that this would occur, but didn't know any other way of accomplishing this. How would I go about implementing a timer for this? I've hardly ever worked with them, about the most I've made is a talking clock.

Comment: And also, the program would not compile if they were not static. Do you have any suggestions to this end? Once I get the program working as intended, I plan on rewriting the code IAW best practices and/or more organized. I'm new to this and OOP is still not second nature yet.

Comment: Tip:  Add @Reimeus (or whoever - the @ is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Answer (score 3):

The `Thread` will block the UI. You should use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). So instead of using Thread

```
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(400);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {    
    }
    blueButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

the code could be:

```
            int delay = 400; //milliseconds
            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    //...Perform a task...
                    blueButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
```

Comment: You're brilliant! Thanks so much! Okay, now that part works, but the pattern is still not showing properly. Clicking the start button just causes random lights to flash. Code in the original post is updated for you to check if you want.